# Do functions really make a code efficient?

Tags: function, interpreter

A program with repetitive lines will be efficient or one which puts them into a function and calls the function repetitively?We have a **interpreted** language that executes both the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the language mostly, but the difference would be very very small (if any). If you want to build for speed, don't use an interpreted language. Use something like C, C++, or even ASM.

Also, you have to remember that programming time is usually pretty expensive for companies, so usually using things like functions that make programming faster and easier is better than having your program run a millisecond faster.